# laravel mutator: access other attributes

Tags: laravel

I have a plain Laravel 8 install, and added a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) that should access other attributes of that model.

As an example: would like to set the name to the name + email address.

I tried:

```
    public function setNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $value .' - '. $this->attributes['email'];
    }
```

And test:

```
>>> User::factory()->make()
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.
<warning>PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "email" in .../app/Models/User.php on line 45</warning>
=> App\Models\User {#3399
     name: "Mr. Johathan Becker - ",
     email: "dsteuber@example.com",
     email_verified_at: "2021-05-07 18:10:35",
     #password: "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi",
     #remember_token: "bihwTV6T4E",
   }
```

So: `$this->attributes` does not contain 'email'.

Can I access the other attributes of that model?

I can imagine that even if it is possible, the mutator can not guarantee that the related attribute is already set.

**Update**: matiaslauriti's comment solved the simplified example above. Thanks! The order in which the attributes are set matters. Afterwards I can use both `$this->attributes['name']` or `$this->name`.

My more complex use case is: I want to create a Post for a User (`$user->posts()->create([...])`), and when setting a post attribute I want to access the 'user'. So in that case the user is already set and we can assume the 'user' is available. But in the Post mutator $this->user gives null. Suggestions?

Comment: Where/how do you set the name?

Comment: in the provided example: the built-in factory (see code example). In the real use case: when setting a Post attribute I want to access the user_id of the User that creates the Post. I have updated the question to provide User+Post details.

Comment: have you added name in protected $appends array

Comment: name is not added to $appends. Is that necessary? In the example code the mutator is called and name is updated. It is just that it can not access other attributes.

Comment: @wivku Try doing this, whenever you set the name, do it always after the email. If you are using a factory, write the `email` value on top, and then `name`, so the `email` is created and then when the `name` is set, `email` already exists. Also if you are doing this in any controller.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! After that I can use either `$this->attributes['name']` or `$this->name`. Do you have an idea why `$this->user` is null for User + Post relationship when calling `$user->posts()->create(...)`?

Comment: created separate question, as this question mixed the simplified case with the actual case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67447632/laravel-access-related-model-using-mutator-during-user-posts-create

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$this->email` instead of `$this->attributes['email']`

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Note it will still be empty when creating a new instance. I.e. when called as part of the create() $this->email is empty, but when called as part of update() it will indeed get the email value.

I assumed this would also work for my real use case: `$user->posts()->create(...)`. In the e.g. Post's title mutator: `$this->user` returns null. Will investigate further and post separate question if necessary.

Comment: Update: that's indeed cleaner than $this->attributes['email']. But it was @matiaslauriti's answer that solved it for the simplified example: the order in which they are set matters.

Answer (score 0):

Set email input before name input, and then you can access the email attribute with `$attributes['email']`.

I did it on the request file by
`$this->request = collect(['email' => $this->email])->merge($this->request);`

Comment: Thanks. Similar to @matiaslauriti's comment, but good to have as a separate answer.